# Add new string between every current string in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of topics

`["dogs", "cats", "fish", "morestuff"]`

I'm formatting this array afterwards to be used as a series of identifies to match within `match()`. Considering this list will grow I'm essentially using this array of strings to convert into a large conditional statement of OR operators. Which will be executed within `eval(x.join(''))`. So i'd like a way to generate `||` operators between every existing string in the array.

This is the desired output

`["dogs", "||", "cats", "||", "fish", "||", "morestuff"]`

Free feel to share a better method if this is convoluted. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a new element in between all elements of a JS array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528616/how-to-insert-a-new-element-in-between-all-elements-of-a-js-array)

Comment: You may do "x.join('||')". I'm not sure eval is the right choice though. Why not just x.some((v) => !!v);

Comment: Oh why didn't I think of that lol. I'll give it a try

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/N53eju/4 response to your deleted question (finding the @@ and doing replace, in JavaScript). Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var array = ["dogs", "cats", "fish", "morestuff"],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a, "||"), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It will produce result like this 
[ "dogs", "||", "cats", "||", "fish", "||", "morestuff", "||" ]